Where NextJS DashUI template entry point?
I have cloned NextJS template from : https://github.com/codescandy/dashui-free-nextjs-admin-template it doesn't has pages directory, so where is the starting point ?
where is the starting point with the directories structure like that ? I have tried comment and rename couple of files to tracing the starting point, but makes me more confused

read https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration btw, the intery point is app
